# How to manage multiple environnements of an application using Algolia search?

Tags: development-environment, algolia

I am working on an application with PROD and DEV environnements. I configured two Algolia applications, one for each.
Should I manually copy every index and its settings (a lot) and make every change in both applications whenever I need to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with configuring two indexes as it is easier to manage. Two applications would mean that you would have two api keys, two admin panels  and extra costs involved. The good thing about having one application is that you can easily clone indexes and duplicate settings.

Comment: Hi! Thanks, I really appreaciate your advice. I created a new application but yes, I didn't wanted to pay for a new plan, so they have different limits. I will switch to a new index + '-dev' :)

Comment: No problem, hope you have a nice day! :)